# Is there a way to find polygon intersection considering its z coordinate value?

Tags: geometry, coordinates, polygon, intersection, jts

I have multiple polygons with z coordinates assigned to them.

Polygon 1 is going from level -8 to -4.

Polygon 2 is going from level -4 to -4.

This means both are at different levels so in reality they don't intersect/overlap.

But when we do **polygon1.overlaps(polygon2)** it doesn't consider the z level and marks it as overlapping polygons.

Is there a way to identify overlaps with z levels? or to interpolate z values of overlapping coordinates to check whether they are at different level or not?

[image]

Comment: What do you call an overlap in 3D ?

Comment: When polygon intersects at same z level.

Comment: Then why don't you just compare the z levels before testing for overlap ?

Comment: but z values could be anything. For e.g. road1 and road2 have -4 to -8 z values but in opposite directions. Z values are the same but the z values start from the opposite direction.

Comment: If you mean that the polygons might not be horizontal, then I ask again what you call an overlap. The figure is not helpful.

Comment: I think what you want is not a polygon intersection but a mesh intersection between polygons which have been decomposed to triangular meshes.